# Sigma-Algebra generated by a set of subset of $\Omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know it is very trivial, but I can't understand the following. Let for example the sample space $\Omega$ = {0,1}. Let also A = {{0}} and B = {{{0}}}. Am I able to define a sigma-Algebra generated by A and B, i.e. $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$? I would say no since neither of the two is a subset of $\Omega$ (if Yes, are they equal?).
Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: A is subset of $\Omega$?

Comment: Well, I would say no since {0} is not an element of $\Omega$. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. Same for B.

Comment: So it does not exist such a sigma-Algebras right?

Comment: Again you are right.

Comment: "*since $\{0\}$ is not an element of $\Omega$*"... at a risk of being too pedantic, $1$ is an element of $\Omega$ and $1$ is technically equal to $\{0\}$ in certain contexts.  Of course, if you treat $0$ and $1$ as urelements, then you are correct that $\{0\}$ is not an element in $\Omega$, however if you treat $0$ and $1$ as natural numbers as via Von Neumann's construction of the naturals, then $\{0\}$ (*which is represented by the symbol $1$*) is in fact an element of $\Omega$.

Comment: @JMoravitz. nice catch, but it fail if OP consider "$1$" in place of "$0$" - I have doubt, that for him is indifferent by which one construct $A, B$. He interested especially by creating $\sigma$-algebras in this way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a Sigma-field generated by a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ ?